# possible glsl compiler bug on samsung galaxy tab 2?

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, galaxy-tab, glsles

This is an example taken from some real code. This doesn't compile on my Samsung Galaxy Tab 2:

```
#define some_macro(x_)

void some_function(vec4 some_arg some_macro(FOO))
{

}
```

The idea is that the "some_macro(FOO)" piece in the argument list should expand to nothing. Instead this generates an error message like "ERROR: 0:520: '(' : syntax error" which I assume refers to the left parent in the macro call. A parameter-less macro (simple #define) works fine in the same place.

I'm not terribly concerned with having to refactor my code to avoid this syntax, but I'm wondering if anyone knows if this code *should* work according to the GLSL ES spec. This compiles fine on other devices fine (like the Galaxy Note II).

Comment: From the GLSL 1.0 specification rev 17;  _#define and #undef functionality are defined as for C++, for macro definitions both with and without macro parameters._